# PAM authentication using ssh key instead of password

Tags: command-line, login, authentication, pam, chsh

When I try to use `chsh` to change my default shell, I get prompted for my user password. The problem is I log in using my SSH key and do not have a user password - by design.

Yes, I can set a password for my user account. I am interested to know if there is a way for chsh to authenticate via pam using my ssh key?

This line is `/etc/pam.d/chsh` seems to be calling PAM

> auth       required   pam_shells.so

Is there anything I can change so that chsh can get authenticated via SSH keys?